# .htaccess 301 redirect example /old-page/?utm_source=twitter.com to /new-folder/new-page/?utm_source=twitter.com

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

Been hacking away at this for a while now. How would I redirect old pages and their folder structures to new pages and their folder structures with everything intact in the URL at the end? Something like:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /old-page/(.*) /new-folder/new-page/$1
```

Comment: What is the problem with the directive you posted? That looks like it should already do what you require? If not then you possibly have a conflict with existing directives in `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^old-page/(.*) /new-folder/new-page/$1 [L,R]`

`L` flag tells Apache that it's the last rule to be executed for any matches. `R` flag does the redirect with 302 as default; if you want a different redirect type, use `[L,R=301]` for example.